# Error: Optimizer (nlminb) did not achieve convergence (convergence = 1)

Tags: r, metafor

I tried to run a standard random effects model in `metafor` using the following code:

```
output5 = map(metrics4, 
              function(i)  metadata1 %>%
                filter(measurement_n==i) %>%
                drop_na(publication_title) %>%
                rma.mv(lnrr, v, random = ~ 1 | publication_title, data=.))
```

But I am getting the following error over and over again

```
Error: Optimizer (nlminb) did not achieve convergence (convergence = 1).
```

Can anyone suggest how to fix it?

Comment: To be able to help you, we need to have an example that we can replicate and it is not the case at the moment.

Comment: See this: https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:convergence_problems_rma_mv